# How useful is SciRate for ...?

Tags: soft-question, software

How useful is SciRate to

- get a customized arXiv.org feed
- see trending papers from selected categories
- vote & comment on recent preprints

i.e. how good (on a technical level, not as a community) is SciRate at those things it focused on.

Since [SciRate](https://scirate.com/) is [advertised](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7463/4846) here, was initially written by the physics professor Dave Bacon, is said to be mostly adopted by physicists (maybe because they were the early adopters of arXiv), and might be useful for research related activity in general, it seems defendable to ask this question here. (This question is subjective by its very nature, but I can't change or defend this.)

I get confused by: (1) The "beta" in the logo, because the site feels mature and seems to have switched from active development to active maintenance two years ago. (2) The name SciRate advertises "rating" as the most important feature, but the actually useful functionality (from my impression) seems to be an easy feed-like interface directly showing the abstracts, thereby enabling easy browsing of papers. The interaction of the rating functionality with this use case may be good or bad, but I found no way to switch it off. (3) The [trackback](https://arxiv.org/help/trackback/) functionality of arXiv itself (which didn't exist yet when Dave Bacon created the first version of SciRate) seem better suited for discussion or reviews of the arXiv papers than "external" sites like SciRate. However, SciRate doesn't even claim that its comment functionality would provide an appropriate platform for discussions or reviews.

Comment: I vote to close/migrate this comment as it not a question about physics, but rather the infrastructure of distributing physis papers.

Comment: If you want to close this question, don't worry about migration. I will take the content of the question then, and try to find a better place (like the mailing list of SciRate). And part of my initial confusion was already resolved while doing the research for this question, so it might have served its purpose even if I don't find an appropriate place for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics.

Comment: @MikaelFremling You didn't actually vote, you know. If you really think a question is off topic, it would be appreciated if you actually back it up with a flag (or vote once you get enough reputation).

Comment: @DavidZ Sorry, forgot that detail ;)